# Logrotate files with timestamps in the names

Tags: logs, logrotate

Seems like it should work:

```
"/usr/local/tomcat/logs/" {
daily
compress
delaycompress
copytruncate
rotate 1
prerotate
/usr/bin/find /usr/local/tomcat/logs/ -name stupidLogWithTimestamp* -size -10k -delete
/usr/bin/find /usr/local/tomcat/logs/ -name stupidLogWithTimestamp* -mtime +3 -delete
endscript
}
```

I want to rotate 1 time on logs newer than 3 days and get rid of anything less than 10k in size. Whenever I try to run it manually I get:

```
rotating pattern: "/usr/local/tomcat/logs/"  forced from command line (no old logs will be kept)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
```

And nothing changes. I've been scouring stack overflow but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to use regex in the first line:
So this:

```
"/usr/local/tomcat/logs/"
```

Should be this:

```
"/usr/local/tomcat/logs/stupidLogWithTimestamp*"
```